# What is this black substance in my pool area?

Tags: stain

I found this in my pool area on the floor of my painted brick pilar.

Anyone know what it could be and the cause please??

Thank you :)

[image]

Comment: Bad pic?  Changed your mind?

Comment: More details are required.  Is it powdery or sticky.  Are you able to wash it ?

Comment: A photo with context would help. I can't tell what I'm looking at.

Answer (score 5):

That looks like black mold, caused by water ingress.

Longer answer:

Theoretically it could be something else, but the root problem is the water ingress. Water in contact with masonry is always bad, that needs to be resolved.

Comment: It does look like it, but need it tested to be sure.  No one can tell just by a picture or even looking at it.  Can also be a leak picking up something black.

Answer (score 1):

To be clinically correct it would have to be tested.

However here in Fla. that is everywhere outside where water is allowed to collect for more than a few days.  We wash it away with a mixture of water and outdoor bleach. (so it doesn't harm any plants nearby)
Sometimes a brush or broom is needed for a little scrubbing.

Clean it up and keep an eye on the area to see if the area dries, or continues to stay wet.  if it stays wet you will need to find the source.